# PaperTrail override column in object_changes before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, paper-trail-gem, papertrail-app

Currently I am using PaperTrail for model versioning an I have a situation in which I invite a team member. The created records after the "create" event is fired up is:

```
<PaperTrail::Version:0x0000558aeeff2b38 
id: 327, 
item_type: "TeamMember", 
item_id: 12, 
event: "create", 
whodunnit: "1", 
object: nil, 
created_at: Wed, 21 Dec 2022 15:57:04 UTC +00:00, 
object_changes: {"user_id"=>[nil, 42]}>
```

As shown below TeamMember model has an association with user and when it is created I save the user_id. PaperTrail keeps track of user_id and saved the id of user but instead I am interested of user name. I cannot do a find with the id when I display the log because the user with that id may not exist anymore in the future and it will result in record not found. On the other hand I cannot use reify because
this is a "create" event and reify results in nil.
Please help me how can I save user_name instead of user id on object_changes.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect situation to use PT's "metadata" feature. Please see https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4c-storing-metadata

Comment: But let's say I am changing IDs, and I want papertrail to not display the IDs, but instead display the corresponding names from a different table, and I have several of them like paying_company_ids, registered_company_ids, where I want to have this altered behavior. If I used metadata and stored the names, how would I replicate the behavior of object wherein it only displays the stuff that changed? Having separate column for metadata would mean, it would display names even if it didn't change, right?